# Proper Filter implementation to check whether user is logged in or not

Tags: java, filter

I have a mvc web application which need to be secured using the java filter concept. 
If I am not logged in the application should take me to the login page and if I am logged in the application must not allow me to access the login page.

Below is the filter code which I have implementd in filter
Login url is /login   (login.jsp)
home page url is /home  (home.jsp)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter("/LoginFilter")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

private RequestDispatcher dispatcher;

public LoginFilter() {
}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session=req.getSession(false);
    String reqUri=req.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println("RequestURI:"+reqUri);

    if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("user")!=null){

        if(reqUri.equals("login")){
            System.out.println("you are already logged in");
            dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/home");
            dispatcher.forward(req, res);
            return;
        }
        else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    } 

}

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
}

}
```

Comment: So, what is the question exactly?

Comment: `reqUri.equals("login")` while `reqUri=req.getRequestURI();` ... please try to follow your code to comprehend what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below updated code to check if it is completing your requirement or not.
where login url is predefined and checking every time for logged-in user to take him/her to secured page.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter("/LoginFilter")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

private String loginUri="/LoginLogout/login";
private RequestDispatcher dispatcher;

public LoginFilter() {
}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session=req.getSession(false);
    String reqUri=req.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println("RequestURI:"+reqUri);

    //already looged in
    if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("user")!=null){

        //trying to access login url after logged in
        if(reqUri.equals(loginUri)){
            System.out.println("you are already logged in");
            dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/home");
            dispatcher.forward(req, res);
            return;
        }
        else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    } 
    //if not logged-in
    else{
        System.out.println("First have to logged in");
        dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/login");
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
        return;
    }

}

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
}

}
```